# PostgresSql terminates with signal 11 when run with docker-compose

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose

I'm trying to run a simple postgres with docker-compose, which is more challenging than I thought. I'm running it on a `Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.1` with `docker-compose` at `1.27.4`.
It fails after calling `docker-compose up` with the following output:

```
mydb_1  | Success. You can now start the database server using:
mydb_1  |
mydb_1  |     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
mydb_1  |
mydb_1  | waiting for server to start....[36] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.1 on arm-unknown-linux-musleabihf, compiled by gcc (Alpine 10.2.1_pre1) 10.2.1 20201203, 32-bit
mydb_1  | [36] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
mydb_1  | ......[36] LOG:  startup process (PID 37) was terminated by signal 11: Segmentation fault
mydb_1  | [36] LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
mydb_1  | [36] LOG:  database system is shut down
mydb_1  | pg_ctl: could not start server
mydb_1  | Examine the log output.
mydb_1  |  stopped waiting
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'
services:
  mydb:
    image: postgres:13.1-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=synapse
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=test
    volumes:
      - synapse-db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
 synapse-db:
```

Any ideas why this might happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue with the latest images (I tried all from 9 to 13).
Looks like the problem is the latest build, so I replaced `9-alpine` version which was commited a couple of days ago with `9.4.23-alpine` which is 3 months old and the problem disappeared.
So try to pick any version older than a week here https://hub.docker.com/r/arm32v7/postgres/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated

Comment: 13.0-alpine works, but I would recommend to use 12.4-alpine instead

Comment: If I try to mount the data that I used with the container which was failing it is throwing a segmentation fault even with older releases.

Answer (score 2):

I'm experiencing the same issue here even when removing the old database by removing the volume which contains it.
I tried with postgres:12-alpine and postgres:9-alpine and same result:

```
...
waiting for server to start....LOG:  startup process (PID 30) was terminated by signal 11: Segmentation fault
LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
LOG:  database system is shut down
pg_ctl: could not start server
...
```

After investigation, this is again the alpine:3.13 hell on raspbian as described here: https://github.com/docker-library/redis/issues/269#issuecomment-778588162
Just install the latest version of libseccomp as described in this comment and restart everything, it should work...:

```sh
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libs/libseccomp/libseccomp2_2.5.2-2_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i libseccomp2_2.5.2-2_armhf.deb
```

Comment: I also had to delete the postgreSQL Data directory and then restart after updating libseccomp2. Then this worked.

Answer (score 2):

The option

```
    security_opt:
      - seccomp:unconfined
```

in docker-compose worked for me.

Comment: For me it worked only for new containers with fresh volumes, not with my existing volume. I also updated `libseccomp2` to 2.5.1 on the host, which should fix the issue without disabling seccomp. But both didn''t worked for me yet.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the PGDATA directory worked for me, but has it's own disadvantage(loss of resources). I guess it has to do with picking up existing volume.
Note: be careful deleting the PGDATA cause everything will be gone.