# Pi Postgres on Docker: startup process (PID 22) was terminated by signal 11: Segmentation fault error

Tags: postgresql, docker, raspberry-pi

I have a docker compose setup that was working before (for several months) but after restarting the Pi its now not working :(

Whats to be noted is that when pointing the DB to an empty DB folder, there are no restarts of the Postgres container and no errors. I tried one backup from the past for the DB data folder but still getting the error. Not sure why?

Here is the error postgres is returning:

```
PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization

2021-03-30 13:38:46.052 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.1 (Debian 12.1-1.pgdg100+1) on arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 32-bit
2021-03-30 13:38:46.053 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2021-03-30 13:38:46.053 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2021-03-30 13:38:46.063 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2021-03-30 13:38:48.195 UTC [1] LOG:  startup process (PID 26) was terminated by signal 11: Segmentation fault
2021-03-30 13:38:48.195 UTC [1] LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
2021-03-30 13:38:48.272 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

Here is part of the docker compose file for the DB:

```
  miniflux-db:
    container_name: miniflux-db
    image: postgres:12-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${MINIFLUX_DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${MINIFLUX_DB_PASSWORD}
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ${MINIFLUX_DB}:/var/lib/postgresql/data:shared
    networks:
      - miniflux-net
```

Info:
Raspberry Pi 4
Docker version 20.10.5, build 55c4c88

I can't even port the data to version 13 of Postgres nor use the Postgres DB folder on an Intel architecture. Had I known that Postgres DB data folder is architecture-bound I would not have chosen it!

Any help pls? Thanks!

Comment: Please see if you find someting usefull at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65877033/postgressql-terminates-with-signal-11-when-run-with-docker-compose/

Comment: I did find that post actually but, unfortunately, it did not work :( I will try again just in case.

Comment: hi, have you found any solution?

Comment: @MordechaiDror nope :( should not have chosen PostgresDB!

Comment: @Sovereign108 sorry to hear it... my problem is that I cannot not use Postgres since I am using just someone else open source project, which is built with Postgres(

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
wget http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libs/libseccomp/libseccomp2_2.5.1-1_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i libseccomp2_2.5.1-1_armhf.deb
```

I my case I had to prune docker then it worked.

Comment: This is a very underrated answer. Thank you Aaron.

Comment: Here I found ready to use guide about this issue https://blog.samcater.com/fix-workaround-rpi4-docker-libseccomp2-docker-20/

Answer (score 1):

You can try this: [Segmentation fault on RPi #812](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/812#issuecomment-770148482)

Raspbian OS has a old version from **libseccomp**, you need to upgrade this lib manually.
If you have some volumes used by container, remove then before start postgres container again.